# Understanding strange Java hash function

Tags: java, hash

Following is the source code for a hash function in `java.util.HashMap`. The comments explain well enough what it's accomplishing. **but how?** What are the `^` and `>>>` operators doing? **Can someone explain how the code actually *does* what the comments *say*?**

```
/**
 * Applies a supplemental hash function to a given hashCode, which
 * defends against poor quality hash functions.  This is critical
 * because HashMap uses power-of-two length hash tables, that
 * otherwise encounter collisions for hashCodes that do not differ
 * in lower bits. Note: Null keys always map to hash 0, thus index 0.
 */
static int hash(int h) {
    // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
    // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
    // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).

    h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
    return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
}
```

Comment: They're [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) also see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here is some code and the sample output:

```
public static void main ( String[] args ) {
    int h = 0xffffffff;
    int h1 = h >>> 20;
    int h2 = h >>> 12;
    int h3 = h1 ^ h2;
    int h4 = h ^ h3;
    int h5 = h4 >>> 7;
    int h6 = h4 >>> 4;
    int h7 = h5 ^ h6;
    int h8 = h4 ^ h7;

    printBin ( h );
    printBin ( h1 );
    printBin ( h2 );
    printBin ( h3 );
    printBin ( h4 );
    printBin ( h5 );
    printBin ( h6 );
    printBin ( h7 );
    printBin ( h8 );

}

static void printBin ( int h ) {
    System.out.println ( String.format ( "%32s", 
        Integer.toBinaryString ( h ) ).replace ( ' ', '0' ) );
}
```

Which prints:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
00000000000000000000111111111111
00000000000011111111111111111111
00000000000011111111000000000000
11111111111100000000111111111111
00000001111111111110000000011111
00001111111111110000000011111111
00001110000000001110000011100000
11110001111100001110111100011111
```

So, the code breaks down the hash function into steps so that you can see what is happening.  The first shift of 20 positions xor with the second shift of 12 positions creates a mask that can flip 0 or more of the bottom 20 bits of the int.  So you can get some randomness inserted into the bottom bits that makes use of the potentially better distributed higher bits.  This is then applied via xor to the original value to add that randomness to the lower bits.  The second shift of 7 positions xor the shift of 4 positions creates a mask that can flip 0 or more of the bottom 28 bits, which brings some randomness again to the lower bits and to some of the more significant ones by capitalizing on the prior xor which already addressed some of the distribution at the lower bits.  The end result is a smoother distribution of bits through the hash value.

Since the hashmap in java computes the bucket index by combining the hash with the number of buckets you need to have an even distribution of the lower bits of the hash value to spread the entries evenly into each bucket.

As to proving the statement that this bounds the number of collisions, that one I don't have any input on.  Also, see [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/hash_function_guidelines.shtml) for some good information on building hash functions and a few details on why the xor of two numbers tends towards random distribution of bits in the result.

Comment: Philwb, Thanks for your answer. I really would like to know, Why it is specially 20,12,7 and 4. How they measure the randomness. Most of the answers here say introduce randomness etc. How it is creating that randomness? Why the right shift positions has to be 20, why it cant be 21 or 19?. Can you please explain that too? Sorry if I am missing some basic stuff.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot say why these specific shifts were chosen. You would achieve a randomness with other shifts.  Perhaps these specific shifts lead, mathematically, to the claim the number of collisions is bounded.  However, you'd probably need to consult someone more current in mathematics to probe that further. If you do find a reasonable answer, I would very much like to hear about it.

Comment: So, in short, this hashing is designed because of values being **potentially better distributed over the buckets**?

Answer (score 6):

`>>>` is a bitshift with zero fill.

`^` is an XOR.

`XOR` is also called exclusive or--it is a math operator that combines two numbers. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

A right bitshift by `n` is like dropping the `n` lowest bits off of the number. So if the number is `00010111`, and you shifted it right by 1, you'd get `00001011`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an [article that discusses integer hash functions](http://www.concentric.net/~ttwang/tech/inthash.htm) and some of the considerations to which they are designed. It's not very detailed, but the main point is this:

> the operations must use a chain of computations to achieve avalanche.
>   Avalanche means that a single bit of difference in the input will make
>   about 1/2 of the output bits be different.

Basically, the goal is for the supplemental hash function to remove any regularities in the input, because those could cause the hash table to degenerate.

Answer (score 1):

`^` is [bitwise XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR), `>>>` is [bit shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_Java).

Comment: _Can someone explain how the code actually does what the comments say?_ - http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable for that kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

`>>>` appears to be an unsigned right bitwise shift, and `^` is bitwise XOR

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score -1):

It is a combination of bitwise exclusive OR and unsigned right shift.

See here for more explanation: http://www.roseindia.net/java/master-java/bitwise-bitshift-operators.shtml