# What is the trick in the hash() method in Java HashMap implementation?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding strange Java hash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335169/understanding-strange-java-hash-function)

```
static int hash(int h) {   
    // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by   
    // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded   
    // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).   
    h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);   
    return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);   
}
```

I don't quite understand the algorithm principle of this implementation.
Any explanation or any resouce I could refer to ? Thanks !

**UPDATE**

Thanks all for  the answers and resouces. Actually I understand how hash works, yet but not konw why this code will ensure `a bounded number of collisions`, as the comment says. Is there any theoretical verification?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335169/understanding-strange-java-hash-function

Comment: The principle is to a) pseudo-randomly rearrange the bits of a number b) without using much CPU c) while giving a uniform distribution. This shifts the number by a selection of bit ranges in combination of 4,7,12,16,19,20,24 and 27 in a compact manner.

Comment: This post: - [what-hashing-function-does-java-use-to-implement-hashtable-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364134/what-hashing-function-does-java-use-to-implement-hashtable-class) might help you.

Answer (score 5):

The main goal is to generate very different values for similar input parameters and minimize number of collisions.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

This implementation is just one satisfactory option of many possible functions.

Answer (score 5):

This function just helps better avoid collisions in `HashMap`.

If you have good `hashCode` implementation, you still can get collision just because you take `hashCode % size` to detect bucket for object.

Example:

Assume, size of your `HashMap` is `20`.

1. You calculated the `hashCode()` for `object1` and get `401`. Bucket is `401 % 20 = 1`.
2. You calculated the `hashCode()` for `object2` and get `3601`. Bucket is `3601 % 20 = 1`
3. You calculated the `hashCode()` for `object3` and get `1601`. Bucket is `1601 % 20 = 1`.

So, even you have three different hashCodes you get one bucket for all three objects, that means complexity of your HashMap `O(n)` instead of `O(1)`.

If we apply function `hash` to all obtained hashcodes we get

1. `hash = 395`, `bucket = 395 % 20 = 15`
2. `hash = 3820`, `bucket = 3820 % 20 = 0`
3. `hash = 1577`, `bucket = 1577 % 20 = 17`

Clear, that applying `hash` as additional step we get three different buckets, that preserve constant time access to your object.

Answer (score 3):

the >>> operator is the bitshift but treated as unsigned.

^ is XOR  (eXclusive or)

So the line

```
h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
```

means xor the original with h bitshifted 20 bits, XOR with h shifted 12 bits

then

```
h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
```

the h from above, xor h shifted 7 bits, xor h shifted 4 bits. Im not 100% sure why its set up like that though