# HashMap.java hash method design

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

In HashMap.java method hash

```
        static int hash(int h)
        {
    .............
    .............

 // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
            // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
            // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
             h  = (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
             return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
        }
```

// method hash

after calculating the hash code, there are few right shifts and bit-wise "exclusive-or" operators, Is there any reason to choose the number `("20"&"12")` then `"7"&"4"`

```
        h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
        return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
```

Definately the h is scrambling, can some help to explain this what exactly is getting solved?

Comment: See the related questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335169/understanding-strange-java-hash-function